# Windows Phone application and external library license - how to secure the license file?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-store, aspose

I'm about to develop an aplication for Windows Phone, and I'll use an external paid library (some of the Aspose products). As many of You know, the license file for their libraries are applied on each application execution. But, if I put that project in the Windows Store, how to secure the license file from being stolen ? Because it'll be included in that project.

Answer (score 2):

To apply license file as an embedded resource, add the license file to your project and set it's "Build Action" property as "Embedded Resource", after this you can use following code to apply license:

```
// Create a PDF license object
Aspose.Pdf.License license = new Aspose.Pdf.License();

// Instantiate license file
license.SetLicense("Aspose.Total.lic");

// Set the value to indicate that license will be embedded in the application
license.Embedded = true;
```

For further details, please have a look at the "[Embedding the License as a Resource](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Using+as+Embedded+Resource)" article in Aspose.Pdf documentation.

As far as use of Aspose libraries in a Windows Phone application is concerned, it has not been announced yet if Aspose libraries are fully compatible with Windows Phone platform or not. Good thing is that the verified/tested Aspose product libraries for Windows Phone platform should be available for use very soon and then you can use them without any issues.

My name is Iqbal and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.